# Code Igniter: Access array elements from controller

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have written this function in CI and for various reasons, I need to assign the contents of the array to variables to use later in the controller.

Because of the way this legacy code is set up, I need to get to the elements of the array from the controller.  How do I get to the array elements in $data['oneResult'] from function below. I have tried a few things like the element() helper. Nothing works. In debug mode, I see the data I need and at this point, I need to assign so I want to do this:

```
$holdID = $data['oneResult']['contact_id'];
$holdLoc = $data['oneResult']['location'];  etc.


public function getOneValue(){
    $this->load->model('get_contents');
    $data['oneResult'] = $this->get_contents->getSpecificRow();
    $data['title'] = 'One Record - Contacts table view';
    $this->load->view('contacts_view', $data);
}
```

I am testing this in CI 2, but will need it to work in CI 1.7

Can anyone show me how to do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a global variablw and assign the data to it..

```
  class something extend  CI_controller{
    var $holdID ='';
    var $holdLoc = '';  etc.

    public function __construct() {
      ....
    }
    public function index(){
       ...
    }

   public function getOneValue(){
      $this->load->model('get_contents');
      $data['oneResult'] = $this->get_contents->getSpecificRow();
      $this->holdID = $data['oneResult']['contact_id'];  //<----here assing value to global var
      $this->holdLoc = $data['oneResult']['location'];  //<--here
      $data['title'] = 'One Record - Contacts table view';
      $this->load->view('contacts_view', $data);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the data to be available the next time you are visiting the controller.
In that case, global variables won't hold the value because of the architecture and functioning of codeigniter.

Here are possible ways, that i can suggest:

1) declare session variables and use.(not a very efficient one)
2) declare variable in config file.(preferred and might just do the trick for you).

If either of the above two does not resolve your issue, elaborate a little on your use-case.
Will give it a fresh attempt.

-- seekers01